# Splitting data in lists to their own columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting a JSON response and am trying to get the values in to their own columns. Currently the code splits the columns. In the columns are lists, some have 3 values some have 2. I need to get all those into their own columns. So each row should have 20 columns. I thought I was using tolist correctly but it seems like I'm still missing something.

```
import json, time
import pandas as pd
from websocket import create_connection
from pprintpp import pprint as pp

data = []

ws = create_connection("wss://ws.kraken.com/")
ws.send(json.dumps({
    "event": "subscribe",
    "pair": ["BTC/USD"],
    "subscription": {"name": "ticker"}
}))
timeout = time.time() + 1


while time.time() < timeout:
    js = json.loads(ws.recv())  

    # filter out dict and keep the lists
    if isinstance(js, list):       
        pp(js)         
        data.append(js)


# filter ticker data, explode adds trade list to rows
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['channelID', 'ticker', 'event', 'pair'])
#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['channelID', 'ticker', 'event', 'pair']).explode('ticker')

# on each row, take data from list and add to separate columns
df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'v', 'p', 't','l', 'h', 'o']] = pd.DataFrame(df['ticker'].tolist()).to_numpy()
pp(df)

cols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'v', 'p', 't','l', 'h', 'o']
fdf = df[cols].copy()

csv_file = "ktick-data.csv"
fdf.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Picture of the current CSV:

[image]

JSON:

```
[
    324,
    {
        'a': ['44956.30000', 0, '0.25000000'],
        'b': ['44932.70000', 0, '0.38500000'],
        'c': ['44955.10000', '0.00406220'],
        'h': ['47340.00000', '47500.00000'],
        'l': ['43734.80000', '43734.80000'],
        'o': ['46504.50000', '46444.70000'],
        'p': ['45559.89386', '45929.85170'],
        't': [55681, 76976],
        'v': ['5169.66125723', '7097.09735074'],
    },
    'ticker',
    'XBT/USD',
]
```

Comment: have you tried to do `fdf.normalize()` ? that should fix it

Comment: Let me understand. The ticker column has a dict-like string, whose values are lists. You want each of the values of these list to become a column?